# Login fails: returns to anonymous user home page with no message

Tags: users, sessions

I am testing upgrade to Drupal 9. I upgraded core and logged in and fixed a few issues with module deprecated code and then was presented with a Twig issue where replace syntax had changed. I changed a few views that had embedded twig syntax to rewrite some results and logged out.

On trying to log back in to continue with views amendments I found that the admin login (or any other user) would not work. The anon user home page just refreshed with no error messages. The username and password are correct.

I used drush to get a one time login which successfully logged me in but the problem persists. I get the following log message of type 'php':

RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/home/mark/lampstack-8.1.4-0/apache2/htdocs/pd-net-dev/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php" at line 1239. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 152 of /home/mark/lampstack-8.1.4-0/apache2/htdocs/pd-net-dev/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php)

Any assistance in interpreting this and resolving the issue would be welcome

PHP version is 8.1.4

Comment: What contrib modules are on the site? For example, this exists https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_after_login/issues/3214949

Comment: Sometimes this can be caused by custom controller code that returns the wrong response or prematurely returns the response. I suggest looking into custom modules you have that deal with custom responses or modules that deal with redirects.

Comment: I would first check there are PHP files with a closing PHP tag (`?>`). That is the cause of that exception, in most of the cases.

Comment: Thanks for the various responses. I do use redirect_after_login enabled but don't think I need it anymore so will test removing that. This has only been an issue since upgrade to 9.3 though.  I don't have any custom modules.